# Open data about oil spills from pipelines, ideally by country

Tags: data-request, environment

In November 2017, the [Keystone Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_Pipeline) spilled 5,000 of barrels of oil onto farmland in South Dakota. I suspect there is a correlation between the number of oil spills (say, per 1,000 kilometers of pipelines and per year) and the laxity of regulation regarding environmental pollution, so I am looking for relevant data.

Wikipedia has a [list of oil spills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oil_spills), and that list also contains a list [WorldSpills.com](http://www.worldspills.com/). However, WorldSpills.com appears to have a few issues in my browser (Google Chrome 63) and I can't find any information about where *they* get their data.

Hence my question: **are there any open data on oil spills from pipelines?** Ideally, these data should be available for free or for a modest charge.

Comment: "Where they get there data" > They provide references to a source for each single incident under _References_.